# Newtonsoft.Json: Very Slow Serialization on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, json.net, azure-web-app-service

I've stumbled upon a really strange problem. I'm trying to Serialize using Newtonsoft a quite large object. In my local machine I have tried to measure the time needed to do that and it's around 500-550miliseconds. However, in our Azure Web App Service, the exact same piece of code, with the exact same object to serialize needs 20-23 seconds to complete!

Here is my code:

```
public class JsonNaNConverter : JsonConverter
{
        public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }
        public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var val = value as double? ?? (double?)(value as float?);
            if (val == null || Double.IsNaN((double)val) || Double.IsInfinity((double)val))
            {
                writer.WriteNull();
                return;
            }
            writer.WriteValue((double)val);
        }
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return objectType == typeof(double) || objectType == typeof(double?) || objectType == typeof(float); }
}

[...]

#define WRITE_TIMER_LOGS

[...]

var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new JsonNaNConverter());
serializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

[...]

#if WRITE_TIMER_LOGS
var swSerializeTime = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
#endif

[...]

#if WRITE_TIMER_LOGS
swSerializeTime.Start();
#endif
                    
jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responses, Formatting.None, serializerSettings);

#if WRITE_TIMER_LOGS
    swSerializeTime.Stop();
    #endif
```

`swSerializeTime.ElapsedMiliseconds` is the number I observe in both environments.

The resulting `jsonString` is quite large and as a string it occupies a length of 3239388 characters.

**My machine specs are:**

CPU: Intel Core i5 10500
RAM: 16GB DDR4 @ 2666MHz
OS: Windows 10 21H2

**Azure Website App Service Details:**

Location: South Central US
App Service Plan: P2V2

Our app runs in .NET Framework 4.6.1 and uses Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1

Can you please advice?

Comment: How large is quite large? When i look it up P2V2 seems to have 2 cores and 7GB RAM.

Comment: It's 3239388 characters long as a string. So, P2V2 you believe it's too small to handle this?

Comment: It atleast a difference to your local machine and may be part of the problem. I assume you can monitor the RAM usage somewhere in Azure to check that.

Comment: Monitoring the machine and looking for a bootleneck should anyway be the thing you should try. The other thing is checking that you actually suspect the correct  thing here. Is "responses" something that has a deffered execution attached? And that just happens while serializing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about deffered execution inside "responses" variable?

Comment: If i need to answer that you probably don't have that problem here ;) Is that an IAsyncEnumerable for example or an IQueryable?

Comment: No, there isn't any of that. As of Memory and CPU, I don't see any spikes in azure portal while running the abovementioned code. The Average CPU usage is 68% and Average Mem usage is 51%.

Comment: What happens to performance if you eliminate the `JsonNaNConverter`?  Any chance you're using entity framework proxies in one setup but not the other?

Comment: Nothing gets better even if I remove `JsonNaNConverter`. Just checked it and it took 28s just to serialize the object. Also I don't use any proxies. Just good ol' classes that implement some custom interfaces.